# Serializing XML in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have the following scenarios for output from a web service (the output's type is string, but the content of the string is XML).

When the service didn't succeed the output is:

```
<root>
 <exec_id>2053c884-beec-4c33-af64-bce8c4a8601c</exec_id>
 <ERROR_CODE>-13</ERROR_CODE>
 <OUTPUT_XML>Policy GO Period is mistaken (Mar  9 2016  8:43PM, Mar  6 2017         11:59PM)</OUTPUT_XML>
</root>
```

When the service returns something, the response is:

```
<root>
 <exec_id>9a506024-8996-4f17-bcc4-a4616b2c28da</exec_id>
 <ERROR_CODE>0</ERROR_CODE>
 <OUTPUT_XML>
  <root>
   <ProposalNo>000334374</ProposalNo>
   <InsPremium>225.40</InsPremium>
   <InsDuePremium>241.310</InsDuePremium>
   <FeesInfo>
    <Fee>
     <PaymentDate>2016-03-09T16:08:34.613</PaymentDate>
     <FeeSum>241.31</FeeSum>
     <FeeSumCurCode>BGN</FeeSumCurCode>
     <AgencyCode>001</AgencyCode>
   </Fee>
   </FeesInfo>
    <ERROR_MSG>Успешно изпълнена процедура</ERROR_MSG>
  </root>
 </OUTPUT_XML>
</root>
```

So, based on this, I created a base class that contains exec_id and ERROR_CODE, because they are common for all responses. Now the problem is OUTPUT_XML, because it's a different object every time so I have a successor class for each method of the service. The problem is when the service returns an error message in the OUTPUT_XML. My question is how to handle this in the best possible way?

Comment: What is the question? Did you try using one of the XML serializers and encountered issues? BTW web services don't return such XML, they follow certain standards (SOAP), *and* publish their schemas as WSDL, XSD documents. If you simply have a REST API that returns XML, you'll have to find the XSD and create the proper classes. Otherwise, you'll have to build them by hand

Comment: A possible solution is to use XDocument and XPath to check ERROR_CODE for zero, and then only deserialize using your model object if it is zero.

Comment: My question is how to structure the object tree with XML attributes to correctly deserialize the response in both cases. This is the SOAP Body - the service returns a string in the soap body, which is this XML.

Comment: So you are doing (SOAP)² ?

Comment: Actually yes, because this services are made by monkeys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the service under your control? (Not sure if that's a constraint.)
There are no attributes that will allow out-of-the-box deserialization of the XML in both scenarios above. You could write some custom serialization but that would be overkill.

If the service is yours then you could define a response class and serialize that. If you can serialize it then you can deserialize it. Then in your response XML you have an element for the output *and* an element for an error message, not one element which may contain either. The contents of XML should be more predictable. That's why we use schemas. But using a class to serialize and deserialize accomplishes the same thing. The XML will be predictable.

You could also get the InnerXml property of the `<OUTPUT_XML>` node and if it begins with `<root>` then deserialize that string is a separate XML document. That's logical since that's what they're actually giving you - an XML document as string inside of an XML document.

Or, as was said, if the error code is reliable indicator then you could just read that first.

Comment: I was curious about the second "error message" - Успешно изпълнена процедура - so I translated it. Bulgarian for "successfully performed procedure."

Comment: Unfortunately the service is not under my control, but thnak you for your help.